# Is there a way to divide two halves of a boolean value in sql?

Tags: sql

I'm currently working on a task where I'm dealing with a table in which every row has a boolean value, "is_important". I am trying to create a ratio of important entries to total entries grouped by date but I can't seem to get SQL to recognize that I want to divide using a WHERE clause.

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Sounds like you want a "group by" om the date variable and a mean(is_important) to get the ratio.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Please provide information on what you have tried and what error you are currently getting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

One method is:

```
select date, avg( case when is_important then 1.0 else 0 end) as important_ratio
from t
group by date;
```

There may also be shortcuts, depending on the database you are using, such as:

```
avg( is_important )
avg( is_important::int )
```